# How to retrieve the original string from UTF-8 file?

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup, emoji

I am doing some web scraping with python and BeautifulSoup.

```
body = soup.find("article")
tempvar = body.find()

fuu = open('tempfile', 'w')
tempvar = tempvar.encode('utf-8')
fuu.write(str(tempvar))
fuu.close()

fupa = open('tempfile')
joji = BeautifulSoup(fupa,'html.parser')
fupa.close()

print(joji)
```

*tempvar* would would contain html stuff , sometimes with emojis.
I want to use the contents of the file tempfile later in a real html file.

The print(joji) produces something like this:

```
<b>mencapai\xc2\xa0batas aksara 140</b>, tapi sudah tentu itu tidak termasuk semua <i>tweet </i>yang tak pernah dihantar kerana pengguna tidak boleh nak luahkan apa yang mereka mahukan. Selepas <b>mengaktifkan aksara 280</b> pada <b>sejumlah kecil akaun </b>yang bertuah, <b>Twitter </b>mengatakan <b>hanya 1%</b> sahaja <b>pengguna yang capai had aksara 280</b>. Tulis panjang\xc2\xb2 nak buat karangan ka. \xf0\x9f\x98\x9c<br/>\n<br/>\nIa juga jarang berlaku bagi pengguna untuk mencapai aksara 280, hanya <b>2%</b> dari <i>tweet </i><b>melebihi aksara 190</b>. <b>Had aksara tweet sebanyak 280 </b>juga <b>mendapat lebih <i>likes </i>dan <i>retweets </i></b>daripada had aksara <i>tweet </i>sebanyak 140. \xf0\x9f\x98\x8a<br/>\n<br/>
```

Comment: What version of Python and BeautifulSoup are you using? I'm unable to replicate your issue.

Comment: python 3.6.3 and BS4

Comment: Are you on Windows? Can you try writing `str(joji).encode('utf-8')` to a file and see if it is is correctly encoded?

Comment: It throwed "write() argument must be str, not bytes".
Yes I'm on Windows

Comment: Make a short script that actually works with a short input file example and post them both *exactly as written and working*.  Show the *exact* output (not "something like this") and the desired output.  That gives us something to debug without guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tempvar` is a Unicode string.  To write it correctly to a file:

```
with open('tempfile', 'w', encoding='utf8') as fuu:
    fuu.write(tempvar)
```

Read it back in with:

```
with open('tempfile', encoding='utf8') as fupa:
    ...
```

Comment:  Thank you , it's actually as simple as that.